# Run bat file from task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a bat file, which I want to run from task scheduler

*C:\server\nginx.run.bat*

```
@echo off
echo Starting PHP FastCGI...
RunHiddenConsole.exe c:/server/php/php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000  -c C:/server/php/php.ini
echo Starting nginx...
C:/server/nginx/nginx.exe
```

It works properly when I start manually.

I added a task to the scheduler, but the server is not started. When I click on the scheduler to run task, it opens a cmd window for less then a second. It contains some kind of error message, but I cannot read it so fast and the characters are too small, so couldn't make a readable photo of it.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled out the `properties/actions tab/edit/start in` input field with the `C:\server\nginx`. Now it starts properly.
At least manually, but not automatical. I don't know what is the problem with it, but there is a much better solution if you want to run a bash file right after login. I put the shortcut of the file into the startup folder and it works properly now.